# Can't open a contained Google Apps Script Project from it's container

Tags: google-apps-script

I guess another way to say this is that "I can't open my script editor". I was just getting into a spreadsheet to edit a contained project. I received the following response:

[image]

But I can go to the "GSuite Developer Hub" and open the project and the container.  But if I try to open the script from the container that I just opened from the hub I get that same error as above. I'm not logged in to any other accounts and I haven't found any other containers that this happens to yet.

I tried the same thing with the most recent backup of this project and got the same results.

> > Any ideas about what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Idea: Make a bug report through the issue traker.

Comment: The above assuming that you already tried to open it on incognito mode, with all the extensions disabled.

Comment: It has magically repaired itself.  Could it be self healing software?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have fixed it self.  I noticed some changes in the Script Editor Code so I'm guessing it had something to do with Google working on it yesterday.